# Linking Ethernet interfaces

Tags: linux, debian, networking, ethernet

I'm quite new to Linux networking.

I have a Debian PC with two Ethernet interfaces, one embedded on the motherboard and another on a PCI card. The first one, let say `eth0` is connected to my router (which is connected to Inet). I want to "link" `eth1` to `eth0`, in order to access my router (and Inet) when I plug a cable in `eth1`. The same way the `eth0` cable is connected to one of my router's Ethernet ports.

The Debian PC should also be able to access Inet and LAN, and thus not simply behave as a "virtual link" between the cable plugged in `eth0` (coming from my router) and the cable plugged in `eth1` (going to another PC).

Is this achievable? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [bridge interface](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bridge). You can use `brctl` from [bridge-utils](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=bridge-utils) to create a bridge interface. For example,

```
$ brctl addbr br0
$ brctl addif br0 eth0 eth1
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.00004c9f0bd2       no              eth0
                                                        eth1
```

So after adding interfaces `eth0` & `eth1` into the bridge device `br0` you're left with the following setup. You can use `ifconfig` to see it:

```
$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BC:AE:AA:34:22:11  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
...

$ ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BC:AE:AA:34:11:22  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
...
```

And the bridge device with the IP address:

```
$ ifconfig br0
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BC:AE:C5:11:22:33  
          inet addr:192.168.1.20  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
...
```

Comment: Actually, I'm using SSH, and when I added the if, my console has frozen, suggesting me that I lost the connection. I've noticed that  `eth1` wasn't in /etc/network/interfaces. Should I configured it manually before ? Thanks anyway for the help

Comment: @MaximePiraux: The Debian PC has to connect to the network through the bridge interface.

Comment: @MaximePiraux - when you bridge multiple network devices together they will no longer have their own IP addresses. The bridge device (br0) will.

Comment: @slm: Thank you for the additions to my answer.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, it was easier to add to yours vs. starting a competing answer which usually is more confusing. If I ever do it and you disagree always feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @slm: I don't mind. I always appreciate additions and fixes to my answers.

Comment: Is this your feed? http://www.flickr.com/photos/58435130@N08/.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9931/discussion-between-evan-teitelman-and-slm)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, that solution totally fit me
PS : On line 2, brctl must take a target bridge as param so `brctl addif br0 eth0 eth1` is the correct command.

Comment: @MaximePiraux: Indeed. I've fixed that typo.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later..
Adding another answer.

First of all, I'm not sure if the `ifconfig` package is maintained this days. 
it is better to use the `ip` command from the [iproute2](https://packages.debian.org/sid/iproute2) package.

A few guides on `iproute2`:

http://andys.org.uk/bits/2010/02/24/iproute2-life-after-ifconfig/

https://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-vs-ip-command-comparing-network-configuration/

https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.iproute2.html#LARTC.IPROUTE2.WHY

Secondly, in your case I would probably use the simple [Linux bridge](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/bridge-utils.html) also, But, it is also important to mention that since 2014 [Open vSwitch (OVS)](http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/intro/why-ovs/) is a strong contender to the Linux Bridge.

Some references:

http://www.fiber-optic-transceiver-module.com/ovs-vs-linux-bridge-who-is-the-winner.html

https://devinpractice.com/2016/10/18/open-vswitch-introduction-part-1/

https://kumul.us/switches-ovs-vs-linux-bridge-simplicity-rules/

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28408/difference-between-linux-bridge-and-open-vswitch

---

Edit: I'll show how to connect two Linux namespaces using a bridge.

**Solution #1** - Using **Linux bridge** (Notice - all `ip` commands have a comment with 3#s on top):

```
# Variables
BRIDGE=my-bridge

TAP1=Tap1
TAP1-BR=TAP1-bridge-side

TAP2=Tap2
TAP2-BR=TAP2-bridge-side

NAMESPACE1=Namespace1
NAMESPACE2=Namespace2

## Create bridge
brctl addbr $BRIDGE

### Bring it up
ip link set dev $BRIDGE up

### Create a Veth pair named Tap1 <--> TAP1-bridge-side
ip link add $TAP1 type veth peer name $TAP1-BR

## Attach one side of Tap1 to bridge
brctl addif $BRIDGE $TAP1-BR

### And the other side to namespace1
ip link set $TAP1 netns $NAMESPACE1

###  Set the interface on the bridge side up
ip link set dev $TAP1-BR up

### Set the interface inside the namespace up - notice that we execute  'ip netns exec' in order to run the inside the namespace scope
ip netns exec $NAMESPACE1 ip link set dev $TAP1 up

####
# Now create another Veth and connect it to the bridge - just change $TAP1 ->$TAP2, $TAP1-BR -> $TAP2-BR and repeat the same steps.. 

## Now you can reach namespace1 from namespace2 and vice versa.
```

**Solution #2.A** - Configuring a bridge using **open VSwitch**:

```
# Install the package
sudo apt-get install openvswitch-switch

# Now run the exact same commands like before just replace the CLI tool:
## brctl -> ovs-vsctl

# And replace commands:
## addbr -> add-br
## addif -> add-port
```

**Solution #2.B** - Configuring a bridge using **open VSwitch** - replace Veth pairs with internal ports:

```
# Similar to # 2.A
ovs-vsctl add-br $BRIDGE

# Similar to 2.A - Just with the addition of -- set Interface...
ovs-vsctl add-port $BRIDGE $TAP1 -- set Interface $TAP1 type=internal

### Similar #2.A (and #1)
ip link set $TAP1 netns $NAMESPACE1

### Similar #2.A (and #1)
ip netns exec $NAMESPACE1 ip link set dev $TAP1 up

# Now repeat for $TAP2...
```

Comment: This answer would be better if instead of referencing external links (which may become invalid), you'd give a quick rundown how do use `ip` to make a bridge, and add both interfaces to it.

Comment: Of course, thanks for pointing out.